# How to keep ranges with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

I should keep ranges (with different intervals) and according values like below:

- 0..5000: 1234
- 5001..10000: 1231
- 10001..20000: 3242
- ...
- 50001..100000: 3543
- 100001..200000: 2303
- ...

How should I store it? As dict like `{'0': 1234, '5001': 1231, '10001': 3242, ...}`?

Once stored, I will need to search for according value, but it should look for a range - for ex., `6000` should return `1231`. If I store it as dict, how should I perform the search?

Upd. There are no gaps in the intervals and number of ranges is quite small (~50).

Comment: How are the numbers being mapped to the range? As in, why does 1234 go in range `0` and not `5001`?

Comment: @mu無, no any logic there. These numbers are just IDs.

Comment: Meta: This is a perfect programming question about data structures, I have no clue why anyone would vote to close it it without leaving a comment  or a downvote and I think I have found another reason to vote for increasing the rep limits for moderating...

Comment: @Kos: I vote for keeping it open as well, but the question could have been slightly clearer :)

Comment: What is your version of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.4 you could use ranges as keys. But since you are using 2.7, this is not an option. But for other readers, maybe this is worth consideration.

```
d = {
  range(0, 5000): 1234,
  range(5001, 10000): 1231,
  range(10001, 20000): 3242
}

x = 6000
r = [i[1] for i in d.items() if x in i[0]][0]
# r == 1231
```

You can improve this to catch the case that `x` is in none of the ranges.

Comment: In Python 2, just use an `xrange` object instead.

Comment: I'll note too that in Python 3, the `range` object has `start` and `stop` attributes that you can use to do a binary search on the (sorted) list of ranges, rather than scanning through linearly. (That is one difference between Python 3 `range` and Python 2 `xrange`.)

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend you store it as a list of dictionaries because:

`Explicit is better than implicit.`

```
>>> rang = [{'start': 0, 'end': 5000, 'id': 1234}, {'start': 5000, 'end': 10000, 'id': 1231}, {'start': 10001, 'end': 20000, 'id': 342}]
>>> num = 10
>>> for r in rang:
...   if r['start'] < num < r['end']:
...     print r['id']
... 
1234
>>> num = 10500
>>> for r in rang:
...   if r['start'] < num < r['end']:
...     print r['id']
... 
342
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could define it as a dict as below:

```
d = {"0:5000": {"range": [0, 5000],
                "value": 1234},
     "5001:10000":{"range":[5001, 10000],
                   "value": 1432}}
```

But I think a class would be more appropriate

```
class MyRange(object):

    def __init__(self, start, end, value):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.value = value

    def has_in_range(self, num):
        return self.start <= num <= self.end
```

And then, you can have a list of MyRange elements

```
l = [MyRange(0, 5000, 1234), MyRange(5001, 10000, 3124)]
```

Finally, when you want to search, use another function

```
def search(num):
    for element in l:
        if element.has_in_range(num):
            return element.value
    return -1
```

So that the search returns:

```
>>> search(10)
1234
>>> search(6000)
3124
```

Answer (score 2):

A completely different (but fast) option would be to use the bisect module and simply add the starting point  and the value (assuming your range is contiguous).

```
import bisect

ranges = (
    (0, 1234),
    (5001, 1231),
    (10001, 3242),
    (50001, 3543),
    (100001, 2303),
)

def find_range(value):
    min_ = ranges[0][0]
    if min_ > value:
        raise ValueError('Values smaller than %d are not supported' % min_)

    # Search for the insert point using bisect but add 1 so we handle
    # corner cases correctly
    key = value + 1, 0

    # Use bisect to find the index
    index = bisect.bisect(ranges, key)

    # Return the 2nd item from the tuple since that contains the ID
    start_index, id_ = ranges[index - 1]
    return id_

print 'Testing standard ranges'
for i in range(15):
    i = 2 ** i
    print 'Looking for %d, got: %d' % (i, find_range(i))

print
print 'Testing corner cases:'
for start, id_ in ranges:
    for i in range(start - 1, start + 2):
        try:
            value = find_range(i)
        except ValueError, value:
            pass

        print 'Looking for %d, got: %s' % (i, value)
```

Result:

```
Testing standard ranges
Looking for 1, got: 1234
Looking for 2, got: 1234
Looking for 4, got: 1234
Looking for 8, got: 1234
Looking for 16, got: 1234
Looking for 32, got: 1234
Looking for 64, got: 1234
Looking for 128, got: 1234
Looking for 256, got: 1234
Looking for 512, got: 1234
Looking for 1024, got: 1234
Looking for 2048, got: 1234
Looking for 4096, got: 1234
Looking for 8192, got: 1231
Looking for 16384, got: 3242

Testing corner cases:
Looking for -1, got: Values smaller than 0 are not supported
Looking for 0, got: 1234
Looking for 1, got: 1234
Looking for 5000, got: 1234
Looking for 5001, got: 1231
Looking for 5002, got: 1231
Looking for 10000, got: 1231
Looking for 10001, got: 3242
Looking for 10002, got: 3242
Looking for 50000, got: 3242
Looking for 50001, got: 3543
Looking for 50002, got: 3543
Looking for 100000, got: 3543
Looking for 100001, got: 2303
Looking for 100002, got: 2303
```

Comment: You test code is saying that you probably got the code wrong. Also, relying on `None < 0` is folly at best. +1 nonetheless because this is obviously the best answer *in spirit*.

Comment: @Veedrac: very true, it was a bit of a rushed answer since I had to catch a train ;) fixed both of the issues you've mentioned

Comment: I don't think you have. In fact, I don't think the tuple variant makes it easily possible to do so, since they can't compare equal.

Comment: @Veedrac: I was just working on a revised version. It tests correctly so I guess it's ok now :)

Comment: Also note that `(x,) < (x, n)`.

Comment: Didn't think of that, but indeed the `0` can be omitted

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume that the ranges stored don't leave gaps between them?

I would:

- store the mapping as a dict (range_start -> value) just like you did
- to get a value for key K:

  - do a binary search over the dict's keys to find the greatest key smaller or equal to K (O(logN))
  - return the value for that key (O(1)).

Comment: It depends how large the total range is going to be surely though; if the total range is small, then simply store all the IDs in an array, and have `O(1)` for getting the value. (If large yours is better though, obviously)

Comment: Yes, there are no gaps and number of ranges is about 50.

Answer (score 0):

This is a competing answer to Wolph's, using his code, but changed:

```
import bisect

range_stops = [0, 4, 8]
range_ids   = [0, 1, 2]

def find_range(value):
    # Need to limit to `0` because there is no -1th index
    index = max(0, bisect.bisect_right(range_stops, value)-1)

    return range_ids[index]

for i in range(-2, 10):
    print("{:2} → {}".format(i, find_range(i)))

#>>> -2 → 0
#>>> -1 → 0
#>>>  0 → 0
#>>>  1 → 0
#>>>  2 → 0
#>>>  3 → 0
#>>>  4 → 1
#>>>  5 → 1
#>>>  6 → 1
#>>>  7 → 1
#>>>  8 → 2
#>>>  9 → 2
```

This is slightly simpler, but requires two datastructures instead of one. On the plus side, it's much easier to make work. It will also support floating point ranges and indexes.